# how to understand "もう何も考られずグーって感じですか"

Tags: words

This is from 'Easy Japanese 3' in youtube : https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxQ93BT5GcE9RAKrXDdjdD96-cXgF4h76r

> もう何も考えられずグーって感じですか

I can't break down near ずグーって. ず means not (attached to kangaerare)? What is グーって? Is it a kind of adverb?
I understand it's translated 'maybe being made to think about nothing, it's all the way like that?'.  I couldn't find a word for グーって or グって. I would be happy if someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially thought this was an onomatopoeia for sleeping (see [グーグー](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BC)), but judging from the broader context (40分くらいぎゅうぎゅう詰め), this was not the case. Here I think グー is just a variant of ぎゅうぎゅう or グググ, an onomatopoeia/mimesis of cramming or clenching.

Comment: Ah, ありがとうございました。(I installed Japanese IME in my PC just now :) )